# Is it possible for a readiness probe failure can mark the pod as unhealthy?

Tags: kubernetes, readinessprobe

One of our application service pods is getting restarted and the Last cause specified is "Error" due to 143 error code.

There are no errors shown in the last hundred lines of the previous container logs. The only error reference is the Readiness probe entry in the pod's description.  However based in all the references I have seen in my searches state that failures in the readiness probe should only be preventing the routing of traffic to the pod instance. Is there a scenario wherein repeated readiness probe failures will cause the Kubernetes pod to be marked unhealthy and be restarted?

[image: Pod Description]

Comment: Do you have the `livenessProbe` also configured?

Comment: yes, liveness probe is also configured. I have seen pods get restarted if they fail the liveness probe but those are explicitly stated in the events of the pod. In the screenshot above, there is no mention that the pod failed to answer the liveness probe.

Comment: Hi, check if you are not running low on resources and check if storage is not overloaded while app is starting up. Have you tried to increase the `initialDelaySeconds` to check if its not too short?

Comment: The top nodes command is reporting that all nodes are within acceptable range (CPU averages at 60%, memory is at 40-45%).  The initial delay is 30 seconds and I can ask the maintainers if they can increase it further. Is that something that can cause the pod to be marked unhealthy?

Comment: Can you show the logs of the pod itself? It seams to me the application never starts successfully.

Comment: I checked the last 100 lines of the previous container and there is no error posted. The lines are just showing it is processing requests and the occasional garbage collection printouts (the platform team is using these to monitor VM performance).